# regex to remove words if it contains a letter/special character multiple times simultaneously in R

Tags: regex, string, r, gsub

I want to remove those words where the number of letters/special characters in a word occurs more than twice simultaneously.

For Eg the input is like

```
"Google in theee lland of whhhat c#, c++ and e###"
```

and the output should be

```
"Google in lland of c#, c++ and"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x <- "Google in theee lland of whhhat c#, c++ and e###"
gsub("\\S*(\\S)\\1\\1\\S*\\s?", "", x)
# [1] "Google in lland of c#, c++ and "
```

`(\\S)\\1\\1` finds sequences of three consecutive repetitions of a single non-space character.

The surrounding `\\S*` and `\\S*\\s?` just capture preceding and succeeding characters within the same word, as well as any single space immediately following the word.